# Power BI - Overlapping points in Power BI Scatter Chart

Tags: powerbi, data-analysis, powerbi-desktop

I am plotting a scatter chart with the x-axis: Date Value, y-axis: Value of measured test cases.

However, since most of my measured test cases are the same, the data points are overlapped. This results in my graph showing just a horizontal line. I want to show the distribution of all the data points even if the value is the same.

Comment: In this use case a scatter chart isn't the best visual. I would use a basic column/bar or histogram visual if you are using value over a date

Comment: I would require to use scatter chart to see the distribution of the data points and whether they fall between my upper and lower limits.

Comment: Can you make the bubble size the number of observations so that “overlapping” dots increase the size of the bubble?